# Have a checkbox add a value to an cell with existing values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

here is my tale.

I have 3 cells.

1. has a checkbox
2. linked to the checkbox to see true or false when the check box is toggled on and off
3. has a value already in it (i.e. 10)

What I want to accomplish is, when I click the checkbox on/true, I want to add a number(i.e. 5) to cell 3. This will make cell 3 (i.e. 15). If I unclick the checkbox off/false, I want to remove the value added returning cell 3 to it's starting value. (i.e 10).

I tried a few ways landing on something like:

`=IF(A2=TRUE, A3+5, A3)`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A formula can't reference itself so you would need VBA (if I understand correctly).

Comment: I think you are looking at event monitoring in VBA. on worksheet change or something to that effect.  I am not that familiar with control check box so they may have some built in monitoring

Answer (score 0):

I believe your expected formula in `A4` will be `=A3+if(A2,5,0)`, with `A3` as `10` and A2 `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Else you could remove `A3`, and have your formula `=10+if(A2,5,0)`